# Import and Save Views are Blank

Tags: saving

love the software, just such an incredible tool :)

One problem though... I started a file and can't seem to save it. I just get a blank "Blender File View" window. Literally nothing in there.

Any thoughts on how to fix this? I'd rather not recreate the file if I don't have to!

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When saving, the File View dialog that comes up is blank unless you have a .blend file already saved in that directory. It only shows Directories (folders) and .blend files by default. To turn that off, click on the Funnel icon at the top right and disable filtering.

Comment: hey @josephhansen - thanks for the quick reply. i dont see anything in there though, this is all i get: https://imgur.com/a/Jfz8op4

Comment: oh ok you mean COMPLETELY blank haha. Yeah that's a bug, which version of Blender are you using?

Comment: haha yeah exactly. it happened right off the bat for the latest (3.1 i think?) so i downloaded an earlier version (2.8) which worked at first and now it's not... any ideas?

Comment: I got nothing, sorry. It looks like some kind of file corruption, maybe delete all Blender program files (including in AppData) and re-install?

Comment: Are you sure you meet the [system requirements for Blender 3.1](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/)?

Comment: Yeah, I'll try to delete all and do a fresh install... And yeah right in between minimum sys requirements and recommended ones :\

Comment: if 2.8 was working, but only briefly, I don't think it's a system requirement issue... maybe you're using a Silicon version, when you should be using Intel? There's two different Blenders for Mac, are you using the right one?

Comment: oh interesting... how do i know which one i need?

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/706226/how-to-check-if-your-mac-is-using-an-intel-or-apple-silicon-processor/

Comment: okay, i tried doing a direct download for the intel version, will let the thread know if that was the issue. thanks for the help!

Comment: looks like targeting the intel download was the fix! hopefully it stays that way haha - thanks again